# Update jquery code from 1.4.2 min to 1.10.2 min

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello can someone help me update the following code to 1.10.2 min jquery?

the backslash it's only cause i use it with php and i need to backslash '.
I'm not that good at javascript and i dont know what changes were made from 1.4.2 to 1.10.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function loading_show(){
                    $(\'#loading\').html("<img src=\'images/loading.gif\'/>").fadeIn(\'fast\');
                }
                function loading_hide(){
                    $(\'#loading\').fadeOut(\'fast\');
                }                
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show();                    
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "pagination_photo.php",
                        data: "page="+page,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $("#photo").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#photo").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $(\'#photo .pagination li.active\').live(\'click\',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr(\'p\');
                    loadData(page);

                });           
                $(\'#go_btn\').live(\'click\',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($(\'.goto\').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($(\'.total\').attr(\'a\'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert(\'Enter a PAGE between 1 and \'+no_of_pages);
                        $(\'.goto\').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>
```

thnx in advance

Comment: have you tried jquery migrate?  http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Comment: Does your code break with 1.10? If yes, where?

Comment: well i guess at loading data since when i use 1.10 all content dissapears, here is the link http://websoftit.ro/lackoflove/photos.php?active=3. i want to use lightbox 2 on same page but lighbox it's working with 1.10.2 and 1.4.2 is for pagination

Comment: Check each function you use against the jQuery documentation : http://api.jquery.com/ to check if they're deprecated or not......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.10.2 with jQuery Migrate Plugin solves the problem.

It is mentioned in jQuery Migrate Plugin read me guide. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#readme

Any deprecated feature will display warnings on the browser's console (if using plugin's uncompressed version and for IE browsers use Firebug Lite for console). In most cases these messages are simply warnings; code should continue to work properly as long as the jQuery Migrate plugin is used, but it is recommended to change the code where possible to eliminate warnings so that the plugin does not need to be used.

To find entire list of warning messages see https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md

Comment: hehe thnx a lot guys, it's working with migrate, my fault was i tryed with migrate without using the jquery plugin first, thnx:)

Answer (score 1):

### option.1

replace `.live(` with `.on(`

### option.2

add jQuery migrate script right after jquery lib to your page